# Using MySQL and PHP to display and group data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of updates i want to display on my page but i want to list them and group them by updates per day.

so example i want them to look like

```
<tr>
   <td colspan=3>April 07 2016</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Update4</td>
   <td>Category</td>
   <td>Added By</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Update3</td>
   <td>Category</td>
   <td>Added By</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Update2</td>
   <td>Category</td>
   <td>Added By</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan=3>March 29 2016</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Update1</td>
   <td>Category</td>
   <td>Added By</td>
</tr>
```

So say i add 3 updates on this date they be shown under that date and if i add 2 updates 2 days later they be shown under that date.

I have seen some snipits online and i figured a GROUP By would work.

```
SELECT `title`, `addedby`, `description`, `date_added`
FROM updates WHERE `status`=1 GROUP BY MONTH(date_added)
```

Comment: try GROUP BY DATE(date_added)

Comment: You can't do this with SQL alone, use "ORDER BY date_added" instead of GROUP BY and write a piece of PHP that renders the title, description, etc. and that renders an additional date row, if the date from the current row is different from the date of previous row

Answer (score 0):

have you try this ?

```
$query=SELECT `title`, `addedby`, `description`, `date_added`
FROM updates WHERE `status`=1 GROUP BY date(date_added)
```

if you want to display then you will need this

```
$result = $conn->query($sql)  
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 while($row= $result->fetch_assoc())
{
 $title=$row['title'];
 $aded=$row['addedby'];
}
```

then place these variables where you want to print the values

Comment: Yeah but i need to display it in a table using PHP is the hard part.

Comment: hey its not that hard. have you ever used mysql_fetch_assoc?

Answer (score 0):

Group by is for aggregate function eg .

```
select month(date_added), count(*) 
from updates 
WHERE `status`=1 GROUP BY MONTH(date_added);

not for conditional query like you want
```

In you case you should loop for you date_added value  (the code below is only a suggestion)

```
foreach ($Array_date_vales as $key => $value) {   

 "SELECT `title`, `addedby`, `description`, `date_added`
 where WHERE `status`=1 and MONTH(date_added) =  " . $value

}
```